# Why did Ravana, Kansa die such easy deaths?

Tags: gods, karma, rama, ravana

I mean people who were slaughtered by them died so severely while on the other hand they died so easily without much so pain ?

Comment: I mean, Ravana was literally shot in the chest with a divine arrow. Kansa was literally killed because Krishna jumped on his chest, making his spur blood and die. I wouldn't exactly call these painless deaths. Sounds pretty painful to me.

Comment: Painful or painless based on the feeling at the time of death daily life how they sufferred the pain, Kansa suffered daily from devikis marriage day till his death fearing when krishna is going to kill is that not pain. Ravana suffered several pains and loss before getting killed because all his son got killed is that not pain.

Comment: Shishupala died quite wasily hust by a disc in one blow?@Harihara

Comment: @Ayush Bora Shishupala wasn't evil like Kansa or Ravana. Shishupala insulted Krishna 100 times, but I wouldn't call this a grave sin. Afterwards, he was granted heaven anyways. His death was quick because he didn't kill anyone or do anything really bad.